# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command '/Users/cit/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

ANY ONE PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS ERROR.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/cit/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/cit/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: i tried this does not works

Comment: check all your imports. you might have imported `dart:html`  instead of `dart:io`

Comment: no its work properly recently i upgraded flutter for another project  by command flutter upgrade force after that only its showing error

Comment: have you tried `flutter pub cache repair?

Answer (score 0):

i tried to run that purchased on codecanion.same problem same line.i tried all that searched on google it all doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).